# snakemake 6.0.5: Input a list of folders and multiple files from each folder (to merge Lanes)

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake, fastq

Good day. I have some directories (shown in bold below) each having some .fastq files for different lanes.

**CND1/** UD_LOO3_R1.fastq.gz  UD_LOO4_R1.fastq.gz

**CND2/** XD_L001_R1.fastq.gz  XD_L004_R1.fastq.gz

Inside each directory, i want to create a merged fastq file that will be named as : **sample_R1**.fastq.gz. For instance, CND1/UD_R1.fastq.gz and CND2/XD_R1.fastq.gz etc and so on. To this end, i created the following snakemake workflow.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dirs,samp,lane = glob_wildcards("dir}/{sample}_L{lane}_R1.fastq.gz")

dirs, fls  = glob_wildcards("{dir}/{files}_R1.fastq.gz")

D = defaultdict(list)

for x,y in zip(dirs,fls):
    D[x].append(y+'_R1.fastq.gz')

rule ML:
    message:
        "Merge all Lanes for Fragment R1"
    input:
        expand( "{dir}/{files}",zip,dir=D.keys(),files=D.values() )
    output:
        expand( "{dir}/{s}_R1.fastq.gz",zip,dir=dirs,s=set(samp) )
    shell:
        "echo {input} && echo {output} "
        #"zcat {input} >> {output}"
```

In the code above, dict D contains directories as keys and list of fastq as values.

*{ 'CND2': ['XD_L001_R1.fastq.gz', 'XD_L004_R1.fastq.gz'], 'CND1': ['UD_LOO3_R1.fastq.gz', 'UD_LOO4_R1.fastq.gz'] }*

Doing a dry-run, snakemake complains me of missing files as follows
Missing input files for rule ML:

CND2/['XD_L001_R1.fastq.gz', 'XD_L004_R1.fastq.gz']
CND1/['UD_LOO3_R1.fastq.gz', 'UD_LOO4_R1.fastq.gz']

I want to understand what is the correct way to provide both a directory and a list of files as input together. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly explains the issue. As a result of the `expand` function, your `input` is two files:

```
CND2/['XD_L001_R1.fastq.gz', 'XD_L004_R1.fastq.gz']
CND1/['UD_LOO3_R1.fastq.gz', 'UD_LOO4_R1.fastq.gz']
```

If you need the input to be four files like that:

```
CND1/UD_LOO3_R1.fastq.gz
CND1/UD_LOO4_R1.fastq.gz
CND2/XD_L001_R1.fastq.gz
CND2/XD_L004_R1.fastq.gz
```

you need to flatten your dictionary:

```py
inputs = [(dir, file) for dir, files in D.items() for file in files]
rule ML:
    input:
        expand( "{dir}/{files}", zip, dir=[row[0] for row in inputs], files=[row[1] for row in inputs])
```

or alternatively:

```py
inputs = [(dir, file) for dir, files in D.items() for file in files]
rule ML:
    input:
        expand( "{filename}", filename=[f"{dir}/{file}" for dir, file in inputs])
```

Overall you are overcomplicating the problem. The same can be done without this ugly juggling the lists of tuples. `glob_wildcards("{filename_base}_R1.fastq.gz")` should return you more convenient representation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am not trying to merge  files from different directories together in which case, i suppose, the pattern ```glob_wildcards("{filename_base}_R1.fastq.gz")``` you suggested may fit well.

I need to create a merged fastq inside each directory using only the files present within each individual directory. This is why thought of creating a dictionary, using trajectory names a keys and list of files within each of them as values.